How can I use parts of dataframe using column name to rearrange it?
I'm working with a DataFrame that has multiple rainXX columns for each day of the month, and I'm trying to merge these into a single column, ordered by date. Below is a simplified example of what the DataFrame looks like:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col = ['A', 'Date', 'C', 'D']
rain = [f'rain{i:02d}' for i in range(1, 32)]
columns = col + rain
dates = pd.date_range(start='1991-01-01', periods=5, freq='MS')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.rand(5),
    'Date': dates,
    'C': np.random.rand(5),
    'D': np.random.rand(5)
})

for i in range(1, 32):
    df[f'rain{i:02d}'] = np.random.rand(5)

print(df.head())

Example output:

    A          Date         C         D   rain01   rain02   rain03  ...  rain31
0  0.724846 1991-01-01  0.639414  0.367906  0.917830  0.697984  0.201039  ...  0.241123
1  0.594479 1991-02-01  0.411521  0.960513  0.364190  0.376364  0.911960  ...  0.773762
2  0.597719 1991-03-01  0.853656  0.909157  0.689504  0.619992  0.499380  ...  0.301950
3  0.054729 1991-04-01  0.268398  0.072613  0.202812  0.407357  0.576621  ...  0.959684
4  0.132683 1991-05-01  0.481039  0.216094  0.179478  0.834409  0.459967  ...  0.135629

The Date column only indicates the month and year, while the specific day is represented by the numbers in the rainXX columns. I want to transform this DataFrame so that the rain data is merged into a single column, with corresponding dates. I tried using the melt function, but I'm struggling to get the day values and correctly merge them with the month and year.
Here’s the expected outcome for January and February:import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from calendar import monthrange

def day(ano, mes):
    return monthrange(ano, mes)[1]

year = 1991
month = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

rain = []
A = []
C = []
D = []
month = []
day = []
year = []

for m in month:
    da = day(year, month)
    
    rain.extend(np.random.rand(da))
    A.extend(np.random.rand(da))
    C.extend(np.random.rand(da))
    D.extend(np.random.rand(da))
    month.extend([mes] * da)
    day.extend(range(1, da + 1))
    year.extend([ano] * da)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'rain': rain,
    'A': A,
    'C': C,
    'D': D,
    'day': day,
    'month': month,
    'year': year
})

Expected result for January:

       rain         A         C         D  day  month  year
0  0.718490  0.994329  0.501845  0.311373    1      1  1991
1  0.573670  0.797525  0.279621  0.138967    2      1  1991
2  0.174612  0.065365  0.085481  0.184512    3      1  1991

For February:
        rain         A         C         D  day  month  year
31  0.847852  0.126062  0.057776  0.050183    1      2  1991
32  0.659005  0.635089  0.644312  0.558772    2      2  1991
33  0.424519  0.039448  0.799669  0.813339    3      2  1991

Here’s my attempt to rearrange the DataFrame. I'm having trouble with this code, particularly with how to ensure the days merge correctly. Any suggestions for improving the approach would be greatly appreciated!
Copiar código
df_melted = df.melt(
    id_vars=['Date'],
    value_vars=[f'rain{i:02d}' for i in range(1, 32)],
    var_name='Day',
    value_name='Precipitation'
)

df_melted['Day'] = df_melted['Day'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)

# Extract year and month from the 'Date' column
df_melted['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_melted['Date']).dt.year
df_melted['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_melted['Date']).dt.month

# Combine year, month, and day into a complete date
df_melted['FullDate'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df_melted[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']],
    errors='coerce'
)

df_melted = df_melted.dropna(subset=['FullDate']).reset_index(drop=True)
df_melted = df_melted.sort_values(by=['FullDate']).reset_index(drop=True)


pd.wide_to_long ?

pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['A','Date','C','D'], stubnames='rain', j='day', sep='').reset_index()

if the suggested solution and the duplicate links are not sufficient, do say so and I'll reopen it so others can chime in. cheers
